How to construct a scalar density of weight -1 out of a second-rank tensor density of weight half without using the determinant of the metric tensor?
A tensor density $\mathcal{T}$ of weight $w$ is a mathematical object whose components transform as
$${\mathcal{T}^{\alpha'_1 \dots \alpha'_k}}_{\beta'_1 \dots \beta'_l}(x')=J^{w} \frac{\partial x^{\alpha'_1}}{\partial x^{\alpha_1}}\dots \frac{\partial x^{\alpha'_k}}{\partial x^{\alpha_k}} \frac{\partial x^{\beta_1}}{\partial x^{\beta'_1}}\dots \frac{\partial x^{\beta_l}}{\partial x^{\beta'_l}} {T^{\alpha_1  \dots\alpha_k}}_{\beta_1  \dots \beta_l}(x),$$
where $J$ is the determinant of the Jacobian matrix
$$J\equiv\left|\det{\left(\frac{\partial x^{\alpha'}}{\partial x^{\beta}}\right)}\right|.$$
Now, given a second-rank tensor density of weight $w=\frac{1}{2}$ in the sense that
$${\mathcal{T}}_{\alpha' \beta'}=J^{\frac{1}{2}} \frac{\partial x^{\alpha}}{\partial x^{\alpha'}} \frac{\partial x^{\beta}}{\partial x^{\beta'}} {\mathcal{T}}_{\alpha \beta},$$
how would you construct a scalar density $\rho$ of weight $w=-1$,
$$\rho'=J^{-1} \rho,$$
out of ${\mathcal{T}}_{\alpha' \beta'}$ without using the determinant of the metric tensor?
